# I have 3 divs each fireing a function, function is opening a modal, but this seems to work only with the first div element

Tags: javascript, html

When i click on second or third div element nothing happens, but first always working, that is, opens the modal. When i change sites of div elements result is the same; when i click on first div it opens the modal but nothing happens on the other two, do i need for each div his own function with different id's
...here is the code HTML and JS

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>Services</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
            <div class="over" id="myModal">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>About me</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>
            <div class="over" id="myModal">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <div class="over" id="myModal">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-container" id="myMod">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times</span>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <p>Some text goes in here...</p>
     </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the button that opens the modal
var over = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myMod');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    over.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display='block';
    }   
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display='none';
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: All element's IDs need to be unique.

Comment: further explaination: when you write multiple elements in your HTML with the same ID, it doesn't raise errors. But when you try to select them, only the first one will be returned.

Comment: If you don't want to use unique ID for each div use class instead

Comment: oooooh man what a noob mistake :) there can't be multiple id's offcourse, i totaly miss that one

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding the `onclick` event to the elements per ID (which has to be unique) you should add it for each item with a certain class.
But my guess is, that you want to open different modals when you click one of your divs, so instead of setting an `onclick` event for every div in JS, I suggest using these functions to open and close your modals:

```
function openModal(modalID) {
    document.querySelector("#"+modalID).style.display='block';
}

function closeModal(modalID) {
    document.querySelector("#"+modalID).style.display='none';
}
```

you can use them on your elements like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 sector">
    <h3>Services</h3>
    <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
    <div onclick="openModal('ServicesModal')" id="myModal">
        <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class "over" to get each div and add a clicklistner to each div like this

```
var over = document.getElementsByClassName("over");

for (var i = 0; i < over.length; i++) {
    over[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.style.display='block';
    }, false);
}
```

or you can use jQuery like this

```
$(function(){
    $(".over").click(function(){
       $("#myMod").show();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sven said it's bad practice to use the same Id in differents places.

You use `var over = document.getElementById('myModal');`
As you can see it's singular so when your code reach this point it only contains the first Element found in your page.

if you want to get every "modal" of your page you have to use `document.getElementsByClassName(over);`.

As you can see it's plural (getElementS).

Hope it will help you.

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>Services</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
            <div class="over" id="myModal">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>About me</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>
            <div class="over" id="myModal">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <div class="over" id="myModal">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-container" id="myMod" style="display:none">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times</span>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <p>Some text goes in here...</p>
     </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the button that opens the modal
var over = document.getElementsByClassName('over');
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myMod');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
for (var i=0; i < over.length; i++) {
  over[i].onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display='block';
    }   
}
 
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display='none';
    }

  </script>
```